# Bind9 dns-cache returns my ip to bad queries

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, bind

I'm having some issues with my bind9 dns cache returning an answer to any query. Why? Can I disable that behavior somehow?

```
nslookup not.a.valid.query
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.0.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    not.a.valid.query.robertfoss.se
Address:  *my public ip address*
```

If I disable the line `option domain-name "robertfoss.se";` in my `dhcpd.conf` (and restart the service) the same query results in the much more sane dns-answer:

```
nslookup not.a.valid.query
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.0.1
```

bind9 named.conf.options

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    forwarders {
            81.88.9.218;
            8.8.8.8;
            81.88.9.220;
            8.8.4.4;
    };

    // Security options
    allow-query {127.0.0.1; 192.168.0.0/24; };
    allow-recursion { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.0.0/24; };
    allow-transfer { none; };

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

I'm running bind9 on a ubuntu host.

Answer (score 1):

The DNS record for the domain you are testing, robertfoss.se is serving a wildcard A record.  Querying the nameserver for robertfoss.se directly I get:

```
$ nslookup
> server ns1.loopia.se
Default server: ns1.loopia.se
Address: 93.188.0.20#53
> test.robertfoss.se
Server:         ns1.loopia.se
Address:        93.188.0.20#53

Name:   test.robertfoss.se
Address: 85.235.31.248
> nothing.should.be.here.robertfoss.se
Server:         ns1.loopia.se
Address:        93.188.0.20#53

Name:   nothing.should.be.here.robertfoss.se
Address: 85.235.31.248
```

So what's happening on your local machine when robertfoss.se is set as the domain name for dhcp clients?  That's easy, nslookup is appending the default domain name to the query.  So, for example, if you *nslookup this.is.a.cool.name*, it will change it to *nslookup this.is.a.cool.name.robertfoss.se*.

Two things might solve the problem.  First, in named.conf make sure the '.' zone is type=hint, not type=master.  Second, check resolv.conf *search* and *domain* options.

Personally, for small networks I prefer [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html).  Lightweight, flexible, easy to configure.

Comment: The problem is that queries that arent related to me nor valid are such as "a bad query" are returned as a.bad.query.robertfoss.se. Why is that? I've updated the question with some new findings.

Comment: Updated based on the new information, dnsmasq is much easier to use as a caching name server and it has a dhcp server built-in that will serve client hostnames automatically.

Comment: You have an domain option, which means each time you query a name, you  will first try to resolve name.robertfoss.se As there is a wildcard entry in robertfoss.se, there will always be an answer.